# InputNumber primefaces not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Using primefaces version 6.0, I have my form (inputText, dataTable, selectOnemenu, etc) and it works correctly, but at the moment of adding a **p: inputNumber** it stops working all Primefaces, (inputText, dataTable, selectOnemenu, etc) To run ... in the registry does not appear any error

```
<p:panelGrid  columns="2" layout="grid" style="border: none" columnClasses="ui-grid-col-6,ui-grid-col-6">

<p:outputLabel value="Tamaño" style="width: 100%"></p:outputLabel>
<p:inputNumber value="#{reporteadorBean.index2}" maxlength="15"  >
</p:inputNumber>
<p:outputLabel value="Tipo de dato" style="width: 100%"></p:outputLabel>


</p:panelGrid>
```

Comment: 'Not working' is not specific, it is end-user terminology, not developer terminology, and 'damage PrimeFaces'? What does that mean

Comment: Primefaces does not work when I add a p: inputNumber, when I delete the p: inputNumber, Primefaces works perfectly, the problem only happens with this component, in the log there is no record of any error

Comment: not work = Does not do anything, does not let me use any component

Comment: @CristianGonzalez it would help if you post an image that indicates how "it is not working". One more thing, are there any error on the page, did you check the browser console? (F12 for chrome)

Comment: The solution is in: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/63940/inputnumber-primefaces-no-funciona/64078#64078 Same question, different language

Comment: That is **not** a solution but a bad workaround (it is by the same poster as the other answer here). Nothing 'just stops working' in this case. In 99.9% of the cases there is an error. The browser console most likely contains errors or the server logging, or if you add a `h:messages` that will show something

Answer (score -1):

According to primefaces you should use:

```
xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">
```

and [dependencies](https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions.github.com/wiki/Getting-Started)

Comment: This is not correct: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inputNumber.xhtml is **not** extensions